# React-admin components on Dashboard?

Tags: react-admin

When I try using react-admin components on my Dashboard component with this code (I assume these are the only relevant lines):

```
import { ReferenceInput, AutocompleteInput } from "react-admin";

<ReferenceInput source="id" reference="buildings">
  <AutocompleteInput source="ProjectName" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

I get the following error:
"Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()"

I'd really like to use AutocompleteInput on my dashboard - is this possible? I'm assuming I'd have to connect Dashboard to react-admin's redux store(s) and possibly do some other magic to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a ReferenceInput wrapped component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110246/how-to-create-a-referenceinput-wrapped-component)

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue, mind you fill an issue with these informations? It would be very useful to the core team to fix it. Thank you! https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md

Comment: Will do, when I have the time!

Answer (score 0):

All react-admin components are connected to redux-form, so the error might come from the dashboard not being a redux-form. Have you tried using it inside a redux-form Field component?

```
import { ReferenceInput, AutocompleteInput } from "react-admin";
import { Field } from 'redux-form';

    <Field 
       {...this.props} 
       component={ReferenceInput} 
       source="id" 
       reference="buildings"
    >
      <AutocompleteInput source="ProjectName" />
    </Field>
```